# Does virtual machine consume ram when its turned off

Tags: virtual-machines

I have a virtual box virtal machine on windows 7 i installed windows xp on it and i set it to use 2gb of ram and my pc has 4gb of ram so i wonder does it use my ram when the machine is off

Answer (score 1):

No. When the virtual machine is off or in suspend/pause state it only consumes disk space. It doesn't use any memory or CPU.